# If we want to retain new users, the help center should be updated to match the association bonus users practices

Tags: support, private-beta, help-center

Based on what I have seen on Meta Stack Exchange and per-site / child meta across the SO and SE network, people able to get the association bonus use downvotes in metas, to communicate dislike, anger, and disagreement no matter if a post might show effort, be good enough to communicate whatever the OP was willing to say.

Unfortunately, this behavior doesn't match what `What is "meta"? How does it work?` says about voting—ref. [Do we want the "Voting is different on meta sites" content to match the reality?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/391348/1359324).

This is just one example of the gaps between what people do, specifically, people who get the association bonus, hence getting privileges earlier than brand new users (starting with rep 1).

Is it possible to change the content of the help center to match the practices of users having the association bonus?

To present a specific case, let's talk about the local copy of `What is "meta"? How does it work?`. Is it possible to edit the content of this local copy to match what new users to GenAI SE will face here?

P.S. I understand that user retention is complex and affected by many factors. Improving the help center is just one of the ways to contribute to retaining users.

Comment: By local copy of `What is "meta"? How does it work?`, do you mean this [link](https://genai.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta)?

Comment: Yes, I mean https://genai.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta

Comment: AFAIK, this help page is never customized on every child meta, even for private betas (like [langdev.meta.se] recently), so I'm not sure why this site needs an exception. I mentioned private betas because the reputation required for downvotes on public beta is the same as graduated site: 125, while anyone with 1-rep can upvote *and downvote* on private beta.